# R Shiny: Need to know which tab is active/selected to update inputs

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, tabs

I have created an R shiny application with the fullPage librairy and I have a problem :

**I need to update a dataframe each time I am on the 'PAGE 1' tab.
But I can't identify on which tab I am.**

In the first time, I just want to print a message only if I am on PAGE 1 in order to detect which tab is selected

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(fullPage)

ui = fullPage::pagePiling(
  sections.color = c("white", "pink", "green"),
  opts = options,
  menu = c(
    "Home" = "home",
    "Page 1" = "page1",
    "Page 2" = "page2"
  ),
  
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
  #                               HOME
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
  fullPage::pageSectionImage(
    center = T,
    img = "image.jpg",
    menu = "home",
    
    div(class = "header",
        "This is the title of home page"),
    div(class = "footer",
        "Developped by ...")
  ),
  
  
  
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
  #                               PAGE 1
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
  fullPage::pageSection(center = TRUE,
                        menu = "page1",
                        h1("Page 1")),
  
  
  
  
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
  #                               PAGE 2
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  fullPage::pageSection(center = TRUE,
                        menu = "page2",
                        h1("Page 2"))
  
)














server <- function(input, output, session ) {
  
  
}




shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the active section in `input$fp_anchor`. This reactive variable contains the value of the `menu` argument of the page section.